# How to add an eslint rule to force explicit return type on functions that have return only?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I found an [eslint rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md) that lets me ensure that the return type is always set. I need a way to force explicit return type on all functions expect those that don't have a return. So, I won't need to set void as return type if there's no return statement in the function. I'm working on a big code base and explicitly setting void as return type would force me to edit a lot of lines in the code base.

I don't want eslint to show a warning on the first function, but I want it show a warning on the second function.

```js
function hello() {
  console.log('hello world')
}

function myNumber() {
  return 1
}
```

Is this possible? If so, which rule should I use?

Comment: Why? If you want to enforce the return type that includes the case where no value is returned. In that case the function should return the `void` type. If want the warning from the second function, then it stands to reason you would also want the warning in the first function. If you don't want the function return type to be inferred, then you have to declare it, whether it returns a value or not.

Comment: @AlexWayne I'm working on a big code base and I don't want to explicitly set void as return type because that would force me to edit a lot of code in the code base.